# I need to create array with named index and search in it

Tags: swift, swift3

I need to create an array with these info:

Fruits: Counts("apple":"14","orange":"3","grape":"6", ...)

And then search in it to see if we have any (fruit) indexed? and if not add it with 1 quantity, and if it exist, add 1 to its (counts)

Answer (score 3):

Here you go -

```
var fruits:[String:Int] = ["apple":14,"orange":3,"grape":6]
let filtered = fruits.filter({$0.key.elementsEqual("apple")})
fruits["apple"] = (fruits["apple"] ?? 0) + 1

print(fruits["apple"])
```

At very first line you create a dictionary of your key and values.
in second line you filter the dictionary with the desired key which is in this case `apple` you can even make this key as variable and replace the `apple` with variable. In return of filter you get an array of filtered values with provided key. Now you simply check if the count of this is greater then 0, which means there exist a value for provided key. If it is there you increment it by one else you create a new value with the key.

Comment: What's the point of `filtered`? Dictionary can either have a key, or don't and it can be checked in other ways. Actually those 6 lines with `filtered` and `if` can be just `fruits["apple"] = (fruits["apple"] ?? 0) +1`.

Answer (score -1):

```
var fruitCount : [String : Int] = ["apple" : 14, "orange" : 3, "grape" : 6];

func addFruit( FruitName name : String ) {
    for (fruitName , count) in fruitCount {
        if ( fruitName == name ) {
            fruitCount[name]! += 1 // fruitCount[name] return optional(Int) so, unwrap force!
            return
        }
    }
    fruitCount[name] = 1
}

addFruit(FruitName: "apple")

addFruit(FruitName: "kiwi")

print(fruitCount)
```

We can see

`["orange": 3, "apple": 15, "grape": 6, "kiwi": 1]`

Comment: Iterating over `Dictionary` to find value for a key is super redundant. Just use dictionary subscript and check if result if nil, and instead of `O(N)` for iterating you gonna get `O(log(N))` for searching in hash table.